# Modeling true number of sales based on reported number of sales

Tags: estimation, predictive-models, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, time-varying-covariate

I have a sequence of numbers of quarterly sales spanning a decade, say $\{Z_i; 1\leq i \leq m\}$. These numbers are not observed until much later. I do have incomplete observations of this sequence however in the form of the sequence $\{X_{ij}; i+1 \leq j \leq m\}$, where $X_{ij}$ is the reported number of sales (generally under-reported) for quarter $i$, updated in quarter $j$. The reported sales are from multiple sources and are updated every quarter. There is a time-dependence: over time, the reported number of sales $\{X_{ij}; i+1 \leq j \leq m\}$ approach the true number of sales $Z_i$. The objective is to estimate the true number of sales $Z_i$, given an early subset of the sequence $\{X_{ij}; i+1 \leq j \leq m\}$. How would one go about building a predictive model of the number of sales for a given quarter using only this incomplete information?

Comment: I would base an estimate on the type of growth rate: if you have exponential growth, take $Y_{ij} = log X_{ij}$. If linear growth rate, don't do that transformation. If the proportion misreported is more or less constant, you obtain that $Y_{i+1,j+1}-Y_{i,j}$ is more or less constant. From the earlier years, you can get a linear regression prediction for  $Y_{ij}$ from $Y_{i,i+1}$, ..., $Y_{i,j-1}$ (take first differences to remove the autocorrelation). If the assumptions of constancy do not hold, you would need an unbalanced panel model.